# Change rows order pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, jupyter-notebook

I have the following data frame in `pandas` in `python3`:

```
               +------------------------------+
               | total_sum | percent_of_total |
+--------------+------------------------------+ 
| Group        |           |                  |
+--------------+------------------------------+     
| 11-          | 99435     | 0.255880         |
+--------------+-----------+------------------+
| Bachelor+    | 64900     | 0.167010         |
+--------------+-----------+------------------+
| Just 12      | 162483    | 0.418124         |
+--------------+-----------+------------------+
| Some College | 61782     | 0.158986         |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

And I want to change the order of the rows including the indexes like so...

```
               +------------------------------+
               | total_sum | percent_of_total |
+--------------+------------------------------+ 
| Group        |           |                  |
+--------------+------------------------------+     
| 11-          | 99435     | 0.255880         |
+--------------+-----------+------------------+
| Just 12      | 162483    | 0.418124         |
+--------------+-----------+------------------+
| Some College | 61782     | 0.158986         |
+--------------+-----------+------------------+
| Bachelor+    | 64900     | 0.167010         |
+--------------+-----------+------------------+
```

I have tried to use `.sort_index(['11-', 'Just 12', 'Some College', 'Bachelor+'])` and I get the following error... `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. So looks like pandas sort these indexes by alphabetic order. How can I re-order the rows?

Comment: Have you tried to use `.reindex(['11-', 'Just 12', 'Some College', 'Bachelor+'])`.  The [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) doc has more detail.

Comment: You are the man!! That indeed return what I need.

Comment: @SSC it would be great if you would copy your comment into the answer section

Answer (score 12):

Per [SSC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1865106/ssc) in the comments:

---

Try using `.reindex`:

```
.reindex(['11-', 'Just 12', 'Some College', 'Bachelor+'])
```

The [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) doc has more detail.